# GitLab CI - Symfony4 - An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: gitlab-ci

Symfony 4.4 - php 7.4

My **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: php:7.4-cli

variables:
  APP_DOMAIN: $APP_DOMAIN
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD      #root
  MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE                #test
  MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER                        #runner
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASSWORD #password
  DB_HOST: $DB_HOST                              #mysql
  DATABASE_URL: $DATABASE_URL                    #DATABASE_URL=mysql://runner:password@mysql:3306/test

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/

services:
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: mysql

before_script:
  - apt update -y
  - pecl install xdebug
  - docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
  - apt install -y libzip-dev zip
  - docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  - mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress


stages:
  - test
  - static_analysis

phpunit-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - php bin/console cache:clear --env=test
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:drop --if-exists --force --env=test
    - php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test
    - php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --env=test --no-interaction
    #- php bin/console doctrine:fixture:load --no-interaction --env=test 
    - php bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never

behat-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "I don't know how run behat yet..."

phpstan:
  stage: static_analysis
  script: ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse src tests --level=6
  dependencies:
    - phpunit-test
```

my **.env.test**

```
# define your env variables for the test env here
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=panther

APP_ENV=test

DATABASE_URL=mysql://runner:password@mysql:3306/test
```

**On Gitlab, during phpunit-test, at the command:**

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:[drop|create] --env=test
```

**the pipeline fails with:**

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
                                                                               
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory                                                                       
                                                                               
In Exception.php line 18:
                                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  
                                                    
In PDOConnection.php line 38:
                                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

**WHY my msql image does'nt work ? Is it the problem ? How can I fix that ? Help !!!**

I tried:

- delete APP_ENV and DATABASE_URL from .env.test
- delete the 3306 port in DATABASE_URL=mysql://runner:password@mysql/test
- ...

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake on definition of DATABASE_URL variable **in GitLab** !!!

It was: (**in GitLab->Project->Settings->CI/CD->Variables**)

```
key:
DATABASE_URL
value:
DATABASE_URL=mysql://runner:password@mysql:3306/test
```

instead of: (the solution)

```
key:
DATABASE_URL
value:
mysql://runner:password@mysql:3306/test
```

***Sorry for the inconvenience***